# Defining a method with for loops and conditional statements

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, ikvm

I have to define a method with `Reflection.Emit` that is rather complex, because I have to do a for loop on a field and have a condition with break and return. My method that I want to recreate with reflection looks like this in regular code:

```
override int GetKeyImpl(Type obj0)
{
    int answer = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < knownTypes.length; i++){
          if(knowntypes[i] == obj0){
                answer = i;
                break;
          }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

My idea to solve this problem was to generate a method with reflection that redirects the call to my original method and returns the `int`.

I need to know how to do a for loop and breaks with OpCodes to recreate the method while doing conditional checks on an array that is inside a class. I've searched for tutorials but didn't find any that go further than addition of two ints.

Edit: Forgot to mention it, I'm using **IKVM.Reflection** and knownTypes is an array of Type[]. The method that im writing is one that will override an abstract one.

Comment: If you can refactor this into a static method (where `knowntypes` is a parameter or a static member), you could build the method body with a LINQ expression tree and then use `Expression.CompileToMethod()` to compile it to a `MethodBuidler`.  It'd be easier than emitting the IL manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should reproduce the method you specified:

```
TypeBuilder type = /* ... */;
FieldInfo knownFields = /* ... */;

// Finding dependencies via reflection
var baseMethod = type.BaseType.GetMethod(
    "GetKeyImpl",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

var typeEqualsOperator = typeof(Type).GetMethod(
    "op_Equality",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
    null,
    new[] { typeof(Type), typeof(Type) },
    null);

// Declaring the method
var getKeyImpl = type.DefineMethod(
    baseMethod.Name,
    baseMethod.Attributes & ~(MethodAttributes.Abstract |
                              MethodAttributes.NewSlot));

// Setting return type
getKeyImpl.SetReturnType(typeof(int));

// Adding parameters
getKeyImpl.SetParameters(typeof(Type));
getKeyImpl.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, "obj0");

// Override the base method
type.DefineMethodOverride(getKeyImpl, baseMethod);

var il = getKeyImpl.GetILGenerator();

// Preparing locals
var answer = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));
var i = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));

// Preparing labels
var loopCondition = il.DefineLabel();
var loopIterator = il.DefineLabel();
var returnLabel = il.DefineLabel();
var loopBody = il.DefineLabel();

// Writing body

// answer = -1
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_M1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, answer);

// i = 0
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, i);

// jump to loop condition
il.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, loopCondition);

// begin loop body
il.MarkLabel(loopBody);

// if (obj0 != knownTypes[i]) continue
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // omit if 'knownTypes' is static
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, knownTypes); // use 'Ldsfld' if 'knownTypes' is static
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, i);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // use 'Ldarg_0' if 'knownTypes' is static
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeEqualsOperator);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse_S, loopIterator);

// answer = i; jump to return
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, i);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, answer);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, returnLabel);

// begin loop iterator
il.MarkLabel(loopIterator);

// i = i + 1
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, i);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, i);

// begin loop condition
il.MarkLabel(loopCondition);

// if (i < knownTypes.Length) jump to loop body
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, i);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // omit if 'knownTypes' is static
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, knownTypes); // use 'Ldsfld' if 'knownTypes' is static
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldlen);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I4);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Blt_S, loopBody);

// return answer
il.MarkLabel(returnLabel);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, answer);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Finished!
```

The decompiled results are as expected:

```
override int GetKeyImpl(Type obj0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.knownTypes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (this.knownTypes[i] == obj0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If you have access to .NET Reflector, there is a [Reflection.Emit Language Add-In](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/releases) that may interest you.  Alternatively, write a prototype in C# code, and then run it through a disassembler to see the raw IL.

If it had been okay to make the method `static` (and accept `knownTypes` as a parameter or make it a `static` field), then you could have composed the method body using LINQ expression trees.  Unfortunately, you cannot compose instance method bodies using this technique; they have to be `static`.  Example:

```
var method = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
    "GetKeyImpl",
    MethodAttributes.Private |
    MethodAttributes.Static | 
    MethodAttributes.HideBySig);

var type = E.Parameter(typeof(Type), "type");
var knownTypes = E.Parameter(typeof(Type[]), "knownTypes");

var answer = E.Variable(typeof(int), "answer");
var i = E.Variable(typeof(int), "i");

var breakTarget = E.Label("breakTarget");
var continueTarget = E.Label("continueTarget");
var returnTarget = E.Label(typeof(int), "returnTarget");

var forLoop = E.Block(
    new[] { i },
    E.Assign(i, E.Constant(0)),
    E.Loop(
        E.Block(
            E.IfThen(
                E.GreaterThanOrEqual(i, E.ArrayLength(knownTypes)),
                E.Break(breakTarget)),
            E.IfThen(
                E.Equal(E.ArrayIndex(knownTypes, i), type),
                E.Return(returnTarget, i)),
            E.Label(continueTarget),
            E.PreIncrementAssign(i))),
    E.Label(breakTarget));

var body = E.Lambda<Func<Type, Type[], int>>(
    E.Block(
        new[] { answer },
        E.Assign(answer, E.Constant(-1)),
        forLoop,
        E.Label(returnTarget, answer)),
    type,
    knownTypes);

body.CompileToMethod(method);

return method;
```

The example above accepts `knownTypes` as the second parameter.  Refactoring to read from a static field instead would be straightforward.  The decompiled results, again, are as expected:

```
private static int GetKeyImpl(Type type, Type[] knownTypes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < knownTypes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (knownTypes[i] == type)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your first answer seems to be close to the solution im looking for. I'm almost done, but because I'm using IKVM.Reflection the operation typeEqualsOperator doesnt work. Need to figure this one out myself. Thank you for your support.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but would `object.Equals(object, object)` or `object.ReferenceEquals(object, object)` work?  If so, you just update the assignment to `typeEqualsOperator`, and no other changes should be necessary.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to declare the override properly.

Comment: Okay Im almost done. with your suggestion the output code results as following when observed in dotPeek: `int TypeModel.GetKeyImpl([In] Type obj0)
  {
    int num = -1;
    for (int index = 0; index < this.knownTypes.Length; ++index)
    {
      if (this.knownTypes[index] == obj0)
      {
        num = index;
        break;
      }
    }
    return num;
  }` and Im not sure why it says ++index, instead it should be index++.

Comment: @DenisDik Either `++index` or `index++` is a valid representation of that bytecode, which doesn't push a result onto the stack (it's equivalent to `index = index + 1`).  The decompiler is free to pick whichever increment form it likes when tidying the code.

Answer (score 0):

The easist way to work out how to generate the IL for a method is to create a simple console application that has your method in. Then build it and run [ILDasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) against it to look at the IL instructions necessary to make up the method.

Once you can see the instructions it shouldn't be too difficult to write code to emit the `OpCodes` necessary.